# What happens when I vote "Leave Open"?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I'm working through the Close Vote review queue, what happens when I vote to leave a question open?

I know that it takes 3 votes to close the question, but does my vote to leave it open offset one of those votes, or is it, effectively, the same as "abstain", or clicking the "skip" option?

Are there a maximum number of votes allowed in the review so that if, for example, 5 people vote to leave it open the close vote is automatically retracted and the question is removed from the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

> ### Reviewing close and reopen votes
>
> This privilege level unlocks two review queues for questions that may
> need to be closed or reopened.
>
> Any post which currently has an active close vote or a close flag will
> appear in the Close Votes review queue. In this queue, users can
> either vote to close the question, edit the question, or recommend
> leaving it open. Edits or a sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews
> will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the
> close votes. If the question receives another close vote after being
> kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review. Questions
> with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible
> duplicate in a tab at the top for easy reviewing.
>
> Similarly, the reopen queue will contain any post that currently has
> an active reopen vote. Users can vote to reopen, edit the question
> (which includes a reopen vote), or leave the question closed. A
> certain number of Leave Closed votes will again kick the question out
> of the queue and begin the reopen vote aging process, and of course,
> another reopen vote will put it back into the queue. Questions which
> get edited within 5 days of being closed will automatically show up in
> the reopen queue for review. Questions which have had a revision will
> add an extra tab at the top so that you can quickly view the revision.
> Like the Close Votes queue, questions which were closed as duplicates
> will still list the duplicates in the tabs above.